# How to modify androidmanifest.xml to avoid auto-start/associated startup for Android app review?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Cordova to build android app.

but recently the review fails.

notice me that, auto-start/associated startup.

stack infos

```
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon()
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1557)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:684)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:684)
    at Oy.run(chromium-SystemWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-1:16)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

auto-start/associated startup detail

```
Intent {
    cmp=com.google.android.webview/org.chromium.android_webview.services.VariationsSeedServer
}
```

and

stack infos

```
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon()
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1575)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at IC.a(chromium-SystemWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-1:8)
    at IC.b(chromium-SystemWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-1:5)
    at iD.a(chromium-SystemWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-1:2)
    at mD.a(chromium-SystemWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-1:3)
    at mD.i(chromium-SystemWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-1:3)
    at RC.c(chromium-SystemWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-1:9)
    at LL.<init>(chromium-SystemWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-1:5)
    at XK.run(chromium-SystemWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-1:6)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

auto-start/associated startup detail

```
Intent
{
    cmp=com.google.android.webview/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0 (has extras)
}
```

how to do to avoid the auto-start/associated startup ? modify androidmanifest.xml? or somthing?

thanks.

Comment: as i know now, cordova android mostly base on chromium, So, I can not avoid the associated startup?